# Setting up a Server as a CDN

Tags: performance, optimization, cdn

We've got a server and domain we use basically now as a big hard drive with video files and images (hosted by MediaTemple). What would it take to setup this server and domain as a CDN?

I saw this article:
http://www.riyaz.net/blog/how-to-setup-your-own-cdn-in-30-minutes/technology/890/

But that looks to be aliasing to the box, and not actually moving the content. Our content is actually hosted on a different box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the tenets of a CDN is that content is geographically close to the client - if you only have one CDN server (rather than several replicated servers), it's not a CDN.

However, you can still get some of the benefits of a CDN. Browsers will typically only fetch 8 resources in parallel from any given hostname. You can give your 'CDN' server several subdomain hostnames and round-robin requests.

```
www1.example.com
www2.example.com
www3.example.com
...
```

This will effectively triple the number of concurrent requests a browser will make to your server, as it will see the three hostnames as three separate web servers.

Comment: How would one go about implementing this? Just having 3 different subdomains point to the same partition and then within the HTML/CSS switch between using the different subdomains? Or can you just have all the files say www.example.com and have .htaccess divide them between www1., www2 and www3.?

Answer (score 0):

Its basically like you creating a "best route possible" server for your client.
What you basically does is putting multiple IP addresses to one HOSTNAME example.
non static content *(Dynamic pages) are on WWW.Example.Com
Whereas the JSP,AVI etc are stored on media.cdn.example.com

media.cdn.example.com looks up as 1.2.3.4;8.8.9.9;103.10.4.5;etc

so the router on the user end will find nearest to that location and that will be your cdn.

another way is to force content be served using a certain route, and as such, pushes the router to do the same.